# Why does macro expansion follow template expansion?

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

As a rule, code example first:

```
void f1(int)
{}

#define f2(a) f1(a)

template<class F>
void f3(F f)
{
    f(0);
}

int main()
{
    f3(f2); // error C2065: 'f2' : undeclared identifier
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled by VC++ 2012.

**My question is:**

Why does macro expansion follow template expansion? I think it is extremly counter-intuitive and error-prone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does macro expansion follow template expansion?

Um, it doesn't. Macro expansion is done by the preprocessor, template expansion is done by the parser/compiler stage (which runs only *after* preprocessing).

What you're missing here is the style of the macro. `f2()` is a function-style macro. So if you write `f2` (without the parentheses), the preprocessor won't substitute it to `f1`. If you want such a substitution, simply define it as

```
#define f2 f1
```

Side note: as currently standing, this code doesn't make much sense. Even if you used the parentheses and wrote `f2()`, you would get a compiler error, since the `f2()` macro takes exactly one argument. You should supply an argument to it if it's a function-style macro that has an argument and is not variadic.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't.

The problem is you've defined `f2` using the function-style macro definition, e.g.

```
#define f2(foo) bar
```

But in your source code you're only using `f2` as a token, not using it as a function call, e.g.

```
f3(f2)
```

Since you're not using it as a function call, it doesn't match the function-style macro definition, and thus doesn't get substituted.